# Nancy selfhosting error on ubuntu with Mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono, nancy

I am using Nancyfx as my restful api server. On windows I use Nancyfx in ASP.NET HOSTING MODE, all works fine on my App.  But when I try to use a linux server, the app crushes as I use this code below

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://ipaddress:1234/api/info");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

the exception here as below

> An exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred
>   in System.Net.Http.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information:  500 (Internal Server Error)

but when I use chrome to recieve the content, seems to work fine.

> HEADERS Content-Type:     application/json; charset=utf-8 Date:        2016
>   Jun 10 17:35:31+51s Keep-Alive:       timeout=15,max=100
>   Link:     ; rel="application/xml"
>   Server:       Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0 Transfer-Encoding:     chunked Vary:       Accept

Is there something wrong with my code or Nancyfx selfhosting mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I know what's going on here. It is because the UWP app in Windows10 can not connect to local IP  address like 127.0.0.1!  All is fine now.